# How to import schema .sql file to a Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, postgresql-9.3, database-restore

I am trying to import my schema.sql file of old DB to newly created Db in postgresql.

Could you please let me know the steps i need to follow to do this.

Env : linux centos 7
DB : postgresql 9.3
I have copied schema.sql file in directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/.

Regards.

Answer (score 9):

you can directly execute the sql file using psql to create the schema in your new db:

```
psql -f schemadump.sql -p port -U username dbname
```

Comment: Hi ,I am receiving below.

[root@DB1 ~]# cd /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
[root@DB1 data]# psql -f schema.sql -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: its possible that you are connecting via a peer network, add -h hostname and -d database_name into psql command. This should resolve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cat old_db_dump.sql | psql -U db_user_name -d new_db_name
```

Comment: Or simply: `psql -U db_user_name -d new_db_name -f old_db_dump.sql`